# Limit products to specific stores when they share common catalog in Magento

Tags: magento

I am trying to setup magento with one website and three different stores and one store view for each store and we have common catalog shared by all the stores.  But the problem is I have some products should be only be visible in specific stores and rest api calls.  Can this be done out of the box in magento? If so plz point me in right direction.  If not what customization do I need to do?

Thanks, 
Sandeep

Comment: Take a look @ http://www.magedevelopers.com/articles/magento-tutorials/add-products-multi-store-magento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Layman way to get this functionality is to create different Root Category for different stores.

1. First : Create Separate Root Categories and create Subcategories
   with same name as the category you are already using.
2. Second: Go to
       system->Manage Stores and assign the different root categories
       created to different stores.
3. Third : Add the products to the
       Categories under those root categories for different stores.

This way your category structure remains same and you can manage to show your products in your chosen store.

Answer (score 3):

There is no customization needed for this. you can admin products to specific websites / stores / views or any one product to several stores in the product admin area

Comment: You can't admin products to show in different stores but only in different Websites.

Comment: Brats that is possible plz 
 
Take a look @ magedevelopers.com/articles/magento-tutorials/… –.Its is provided by R.S

Comment: Your url is not clickable.